# Split a string ( {a},{b} ) with RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string object that is returned by an API. It looks like this:

```
{Apple},{"A tree"},{Three2},{123},{A bracket {},{Two brackets {}},{}
```

I only need to split at commas that have `}` and `{` on both sides, which I want to keep them as part of the returned result. Doing split("},{") results in first and last entries having leading and trailing brackets, and when there is only one element returned, I have to make additional checks to ensure I don't add any extra brackets to first and last (which is same as first) elements.

I hope there is an elegant RegExp to split at `,`, surrounded by `}{`.

Comment: There is going to be problem if an input like `{"A Tree},{inside"}` comes up, though.

Comment: We hope so too. Good luck :)

Comment: Isn't that notation inconsistent?  Shouldn't it be: {Apple},{"A tree"},{Three2},{123},{{A bracket {}},{Two brackets {}}},{}

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired output? What should a string like `{abc},{one{two}three},{{hey},{there}}` result in?

Comment: @Robin It is split at commas, so `{abc}` `{one{two}three}` `{{hey}` `{there}}`. However I trust the source of data not to use `},{` within the output.

Comment: So you don't want any trailing open bracket in the output, right? Do you also trust the source not to enter stuff like `{foo{bar}, foobar,{hey}}`? BTW you should checkout @10cls's comment and maybe update your question, your example doesn't seem well formatted (desired output for this one would be nice to).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a positive lookahead to match only a comma which is followed by curly braces. I've tested this and it works:

```
var apiResponse = "{Apple},{\"A tree\"},{Three2},{123},{A bracket {},{Two brackets {}},{}";
var split = apiResponse.split(/,(?={)/);
console.log("Split length is "+split.length);
for(i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
    console.log("split["+i+"] is: "+split[i]);
}
```

The `(?=\{)` means "must be immediately followed by an opening curly brace".

To read about lookaheads, see [this regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: You were right, @nhahtdh JavaScript does not support lookbehind so I've edited my answer so that it no longer relies on a lookbehind. Very surprising that JavaScript still does not support this ages old feature of regular expressions.

Comment: This solution still has the same problem with `{"A Tree},{inside"}`, though.

Comment: It does, yes, but that's a natural limitation of regular expressions. To extract from strings that are not well behaved, such as that example, you have to switch to using a dedicated parser which understands the tokens in the string.

Comment: Matching a string is still within power of regular expression (even in theoretical sense). If anything, bracket balance is outside the power of most regex engines, except those that allow recursion. If we ignore bracket balancing, we still need sticky flag `y`, which is not supported in most browsers, except Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _data = '{Apple},{"A tree"},{Three2},{123},{A bracket {},{Two brackets {}},{}';
var _items = [];

var re = /(^|,){(.*?)}(?=,{|$)/g;
var m;
while ((m = re.exec(_data)) !== null){
    _items.push(m[2]);
}
```

You can test it out using jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wao20/SgFx7/24/

**Regex breakdown:**

- **(^|,)**  Start of the string or by a comma
- **{**     A literal bracket "{"
- **(.*?)**  Non-greedy match between two brackets (for more
  info http://javascript.info/tutorial/greedy-and-lazy)
- **}**     A literal bracket "}"
- **(?=,{|$)** Look ahead and non-comsuming (match a comma ",{" or end of
  string) without the look ahead it will eat up the comma and you end up with only every other items.

**Update**: Changed regex to address Robin's comments.

```
/(^|,)\{(.*?)\}(?=,|$)/g   to   /(^|,){(.*?)}(?=,{|$)/g
```

Comment: A few comments: 1) you don't need to escape `{` if it's not followed by `,` or a number, and you don't need to escape `}` if it's not part of a `{n,m}` pattern. 2) This would match `{foo{bar}, foobar,{hey}}` as `{foo{bar}` and `,{hey}`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the string as provided - it doesn't account for whitespace between braces and commas, nor does it retain the brace-comma-brace pattern within quotes.

```
var str = '{Apple},{"A tree"},{Three2},{123},{A bracket {},{Two brackets {}},{}';
var parts = [];

var nextIndex = function(str) {
    return (str.search(/},{/) > -1) ? str.search(/},{/) + 1 : null;
};

while (nextIndex(str)) {
    parts.push(str.slice(0, nextIndex(str)));
    str = str.slice(nextIndex(str) + 1);
}

parts.push(str); // Final piece

console.log(parts);
```